# Bad global gitconfig file at non-existent path

Tags: git, configuration, config, git-for-windows

I messed up my git installation by using `git config --global --edit` to edit the file manually. I changed some stuff in Notepad++, saved and closed it. Apparently I misspelled something because every  `git config --global ..` command gives me:

```
fatal: bad config line 5 in file H://.gitconfig
```

I cold easily fix this if I just knew where this file is located but I can't seem to find it. I tried every location mentioned online (userdir, Program Files AppData\Local etc.) but it is nowhere to be found.

It says `H://.gitconfig` in the error but I don't have a `H:`-drive. I also searched my entire computer and couldn't find it anywhere while git doesn't seem to have a problem checking it for errors every time I use `git config`.

Basically my questions are:

- Can I somehow reset my global config via cli?
- Where else could I look for my global config file?
- How could I track down the file?

I'm using an up-to-date Windows and the newest git.

EDIT: **I tried** restarting my PC and **uninstalling and reinstalling *git for Windows*** but the issue persists. Interestingly I can edit the global config with an elevated commandline or powershell which results in a gitconfig being created in my userdir. But if I edit or delete it, it does not affect the problem I have with normal commandline or powershell.

Comment: "but I don't have a `H:`-drive"—maybe Git thinks you do. The location of `.gitconfig` can be configured, e.g. via environment variables. What's your `%HOME%` set to? Do you have an `%XDG_CONFIG_HOME%` variable set? See [this post](https://superuser.com/a/341193/312289) if you don't know how to check.

Comment: @Chris My `%HOME%` was set to my userdir and I did not have the other env var set. After I created a new one (see answer) it appeared under `%HOME%\.gitconfig`. Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: Can you, in Notepad++, see the path of the file currently opened (either displayed somewhere, or by doing "file->save as" some programs default to the directory where the file currently is)? If so, you can see what is the file opened by `git config --global --edit` and therefore debug what caused the issue.

Comment: @padawin If I issue that command I get `fatal: bad config line 5 in file H://.gitconfig`. That's why I can't open it in Notepad++

Comment: Ok, so you ran it the first time, did some changes, quit your editor and from this point it stopped working, right? Since it does not happen anymore (after rebooting), are you able to open the file, see its location and try to reproduce the changes you did to make it break again, so we can know what triggered the error?

Comment: @padawin If I create a new one with elevated commandline it get's created in my userdir

Comment: From here, you can edit it, try to reproduce the issue created in your question, and once it's pinpointed, you can add in the answer what triggered the error 'fatal: bad config line 5 in file H://.gitconfig` (Because I'm very curious to know where the problem came from :-) )

Comment: I realized I'm still experiencing the problem I described. See the edit for more context. Also to this: *Ok, so you ran it the first time, did some changes, quit your editor and from this point it stopped working, right?* - Yes, that's correct. But it doesn't seem to be a problem when the cli I'm using is elevated.

Answer (score 0):

The .gitconfig and .ssl directory location is derived from the HOME environment variable.  If HOME is set incorrectly you will experience .gitconfig problems like you described.

Normally HOME points to C:\users\yourusername.  Some applications, like ORCAD, might change the HOME variable which will cause git and SSL to look in the wrong place for for known_host, .ssl files/keys and .gitconfig

Use:  git config --global -l  to verify git can find the correct .gitconfig file.

Example of error from incorrect HOME variable causing .ssl and .gitconfig problems:

C:>git config --global -l
fatal: unable to read config file 'C:/SPB_Data/.gitconfig': No such file or directory

From the console:
To change the HOME variable:

set HOME=C:\users\yourusername

To view the HOME variable:

set HOME

Answer (score -1):

Try to rename the file (into `gitconfig-old` for example), then see if things work without. If they do, add one section after the other to pinpoint the faulty one.

On a side note, I'd suggest to add to Git and Github/Gitlab/other your configuration, along with other configs you have (e.g. `.vimrc`, `tmux.conf`.....), which would make it easier to maintain and to use across computers (if you share it between your work computer and home computer for example).

Comment: How do you propose to rename a file that I can't find?

Comment: `git config --global` affects the `.gitconfig` in your home, so that's the one to rename. You are on Windows I guess, if you open git bash, you will be in your home, that's where the .gitconfig is.

Comment: Could you maybe delete your answer so I can delete my question? I don't think it will be useful to anyone

Answer (score -1):

Corrected:

$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config - Second user-specific configuration file. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/config will be used. Any single-valued variable set in this file will be overwritten by whatever is in ~/.gitconfig. It is a good idea not to create this file if you sometimes use older versions of Git, as support for this file was added fairly recently

Comment: $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set. $HOME/.config/git does not exist.

Comment: Could you maybe delete your answer so I can delete my question? I don't think it will be useful to anyone